# ASP.NET MVC singleton or static class to pass around data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I'm creating a controller that will serve the combined/minified versions of my JavaScript and CSS. I need to somewhere along the line define which scripts/styles to be loaded.

When a request is made, for example for `style.css?VersionNumberHere`, it will check if the combined/minified data is already in the `HttpContext.Cache`, if so spit it out. Otherwise, I need to look up the definition that makes up `style.css`.

I created a `Script/StyleBuilder` (that inherits from `ContentBuilder`) that will store all the paths that need to be combined and then squished (so this would be the definition of `style.css`).

Where should I be storing these references to the "builders"? Should they be in a static class or a singleton that implements an interface so that it can be tested?

Here's the interface that the abstract class `ContentBuilder` implements (you can easily imagine the implementation):

```
public interface IContentBuilder : IEnumerable<string>
{
    string Name { get; }
    int Count { get; }
    string[] ValidExtensions { get; }
    void Add(string path);
    bool ValidatePath(string path);
    string GetHtmlReference(); // Spits out <script>, or <link> depending on implementation.
    string Build(); // Minifies, combines etc.
}
```

And here is *ideally* what I'd like to be able to do with these:

```
ContentBuilderContainer.Current.Add("main.js", c => new ScriptBuilder()
{
    "/path/to/test.js",
    "/path/to/test2.js",
    "/path/to/test3.js"  
});

ContentBuilderContainer.Current.Add("style.css", c => new StyleBuilder()
{
    "/path/to/style.css",
    "/path/to/test.less"
});
```

Then to output all the HTML for all registered IContentBuilder:

```
ContentBuilder.Container.Current.BuildHtml();
```

Comment: out of interest, where did you get the idea of serving static content via the Controller? Can't you just use ResolveUrl? (and of course minify/combine prior, using a post-build action)

Comment: @RPM - Well I had originally been doing the post-build action way but realized that this would limit possibilities on caching and too much mucking around with the build. I also wanted to be able to join CSS files in multiple groups (example main.css and IE.css for IE specific stuff).

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky - fair enough, to each there own. We use the .NET port of the YUI compressor as a post-build event. My opinion is that only the minified files should be pushed out the server. What you're doing here is constantly "minifiying" source files into combined files. Of course YUI does both JS/CSS, and you have full control over the target files. As i said though, to each there own.

Comment: @RPM - I'm confused. I *am* only combining/minfying when there's a miss in the cache (and that could be a while if the cache is for a couple days or more). I first combine all files and *then* minify. With JS I too use the YUI compressor and since I'm using dotLESS for style, I use the dotLESS compiler.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky - yes i know that, my point is you are pushing out the source/uncompressed/unmified to the server (when you deploy), and then your code is combining/minifying. Therefore having the source/uncompressed/unminified files on the server in the first place is meaningless, as you will never be directly serving this content. Know what i mean? Unless i'm missing something.

Comment: @RPM - Yeah that's a good point about having the raw files on the server and serving out something different. I just don't have a lot of control over *what's* minified/combined (say into groups like the IE.css issue) when using post-build events. One thing to note though: when you do the minification post-build, don't you still have your raw CSS/js as well? So aren't you still running into the same issue?

Comment: When we deploy, we run a "Release" build on our local machine, to a target folder. This will combine/minify the CSS/JS into that target folder. The contents of the target folder is what gets deployed. Therefore, the source files never get deployed. But yes, sometimes setting up these groups can be tedious. But it's a once off investment which benefits tenfold. Anyway, at the risk of this being a forum - we'll stop, as i'm not really helping with your solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following interface:

```
public interface IContentBuilderContainer
{
    int Count { get; }
    bool Add(string name, Func<IContentBuilder> contentBuilder);
    string RenderHtml();
}
```

And then in the implmentation of `ContentBuilderContainer`:

```
public class ContentBuilderContainer : IContentBuilderContainer
{

    // Other members removed for simplicity.

    #region Static Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the current content builder container.
    /// </summary>
    public static IContentBuilderContainer Current
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Static Constructors

    static ContentBuilderContainer()
    {
        ContentBuilderContainer.Current = new ContentBuilderContainer();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

This way there's a single `ContentBuilderContainer` living at one time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check out [SquishIt](http://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt). Some more info on it in [this blog post](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/05/26/SquishIt-The-Friendly-ASPNET-JavaScript-and-CSS-Squisher.aspx).  We use it in production.

Comment: That has some nice features.  I like not needing the controller or the configuration.

Comment: Yeah I looked at SquishIt before going this route. I'm mostly doing it for my own learning benefit. I'd also like to make the minifiers etc swappable for another framework (perhaps something other than YUI etc).

Comment: Scratch what I just said about swappable minifiers etc in SquishIt; it does have support for them :).

Answer (score 0):

Attach caching attributes to your controller actions and cache by parameter like this:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 7200, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam = "jsPath;ServerHost")]
[CompressFilter]
// Minifies, compresses JavaScript files and replaces tildas "~" with input serverHost address 
// (for correct rewrite of paths inside JS files) and stores the response in client (browser) cache for a day
[ActionName("tildajs")]
public virtual JavaScriptResult ResolveTildasJavaScript(string jsPath, string serverHost)
...
```

Comment: I know how to do caching - that isn't the problem. The problem is combining *multiple files* into one. Then a name is generated (like `script.js?a4fj6k4j93k`) and then it is the *only* script that is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I helped write some code that did this recently.  Here's a high level overview of the solution that was implemented.  Hopefully it will give you some good ideas.

**Configuration:** We created custom configuration elements that define a key and their a corresponding list of directories.  So the key JS is linked to our /Content/Scripts folder, and CSS is linked to our /Content/Styles folder.  I have seen other solutions where the configuration allowed for individual files to be listed.

**Controller:** The controller was set up to receive requests something along the lines of /Content/Get/JS and /Content/Get/CSS.  The controller uses the configuration key and client request headers to come up with a cache key that identifies the content we want to serve: JS-MSIE-ZIP, CSS-FFX, etc.  The controller then checks our cache service.  If the content is not there, it gets concatenated, minified, compressed, cached and then served.  Handy fallout is that the content is compressed before going into the cache instead of every time it's served.

**View:** In the View, the links are set up like this:

```
<link href="<%: Url.Action("Get", "Content", new { key = "CSS" }) %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Cache Service:** We're using an existing cache service we have that just wraps the application cache.  At some point we'll probably move that to Velocity or something similar.  If the amount of CSS and JS we cache keeps growing, we'll probably change the format of the key to a proper filename and move the content to the file system.  But, memory's pretty cheap, we'll see what happens.

**Reasoning:** (if it matters)

We did this in order to keep the JavaScript for different features in separate files in source control without having to link to all of the files individually in the HTML.  Because we configure our content by directory and not individual files, we can also run a full minification during production builds to speed up the whole run time process somewhat.  Yet we still get the benefit of determining which content to serve based on the client browser, and cached compressed versions.

In development, the system can be set up with a quick configuration change so that every request rebuilds the JS.  The files are concatenated with file names injected in comments for easy searching, but the content is not minified and nothing is cached anywhere.  This allows us to change, test and debug the JS without recompiling the application.

Couldn't quite find all these features in a package out there so we spent a couple of days and built it.  Admittedly some features were just for fun, but that's why we like doing what we do. =)

Comment: Yeah this is sort of the thing that I'm going towards. I can't really find anything that *fully* suits my needs so I'm rolling my own for my own projects. Perhaps in the future, I'll make it open source. This project is also just for my learning benefit as well :).